# packer docker builder configure docker in docker image

Tags: docker, build, packer, docker-in-docker

I'm trying to provision docker:dind image with packer which will build another docker image and run it inside docker with following build script:

```
{
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "docker",
      "image": "docker:dind",
      "privileged": true,
      "commit": "true"
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "type": "file",
      "source": "../docker/",
      "destination": "/docker"
    },
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "inline": [
        "docker build -t my-service /docker"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "post-processors": [
    [
      {
        "type": "docker-tag",
        "repository": "my-service",
        "tag": "latest"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

When I run this script it fails with following error:

```
$ packer build build.json
docker output will be in this color.

==> docker: Creating a temporary directory for sharing data...
==> docker: Pulling Docker image: docker:dind
    docker: dind: Pulling from library/docker
    docker: Digest: sha256:21fe82c6e54e2db31e64f79ec7ac75c6a8f7469cdc56687ced97d6fc3e75e6cd
    docker: Status: Image is up to date for docker:dind
==> docker: Starting docker container...
    docker: Run command: docker run --privileged -v C:\Users\user\packer.d\tmp:/packer-files -d -i -t --entrypoint=/bin/sh -- docker:dind
    docker: Container ID: 7fa2ae91eaf6111ce6d0567f1e523100c777311449454b0df8d6d49c84c477d6
==> docker: Using docker communicator to connect: 172.17.0.2
==> docker: Uploading ../docker/ => /docker
==> docker: Provisioning with shell script: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\packer-shell164551847
==> docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
==> docker: Killing the container: 7fa2ae91eaf6111ce6d0567f1e523100c777311449454b0df8d6d49c84c477d6
Build 'docker' errored: Script exited with non-zero exit status: 1.Allowed exit codes are: [0]

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> docker: Script exited with non-zero exit status: 1.Allowed exit codes are: [0]

==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
```

The problem is that when packer starts the container it overrides default entrypoint ["dockerd-entrypoint.sh"] which was configured in the docker:dind image with it's own entrypoint ["/bin/sh"]. This prevents docker inside docker process to start and shell script cannot be executed.

I have tried changing entrypoint and run_command with below options but in first case it has no effect (I assume it will be updated at the end when the image is committed) and in the latter it can't execute any scripts.

```
"changes": [
  "ENTRYPOINT [dockerd-entrypoint.sh]"
],
"run_command": ["-d", "-i", "-t", "--entrypoint=dockerd-entrypoint.sh", "--", "{{.Image}}"]
```

Another option was to run "[dockerd-entrypoint.sh]" as inline shell script (first), but this blocked the process and didn't execute next steps.

I'm running out of options and I need some help with understanding how does it works and if there is some solution.

Answer (score 1):

In your `inline` section start with running the docker daemon in the background with something like `dockerd-entrypoint.sh & sleep 5`.

Comment: The process is still blocked and packer can't execute next steps. Have you tried that with my build script?

Comment: When I try run the container from command line with "docker run --privileged -d -i -t --entrypoint=/bin/sh -- docker:dind" and then connect to it and run "dockerd-entrypoint.sh & sleep 5" it works as expected. With inline script it doesn't run the process in background.